# Firebug lite not working in IE/Chrome

Tags: firebug-lite

I am trying to install firebug lite onto IE and Chrome.  The documentation states to simply add the javascript location in the document and all should be well.  This works but the iframe containing then firebug is hidden with a visibility: hidden attribute.  I am unable to find anywhere to actually activate the firebug, normally you would think you could right click and "inspect" but that option is not there.  The chrome extension and bookmarklet works but my main concern is trying to firebug through internet explorer.

Anyone had or solved this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah I had the same problem using the stable channel. I switched to the debug channel & it worked perfectly, opening right up. So use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Also, I find it useful to throw a quick 300px-high div in there at the bottom of my page to make room for Firebug Lite, like this:

```
<div style="display:block; height:300px; background:blue;"></div>
```

Just don't forget to remove it with the FBL script tag!